# PHP-FPM log messages

Tags: php

I have two different opinions regarding a log entry of the PHP FastCGI Process Manager:

> [17-May-2023 18:02:19] NOTICE: [pool xxxxxx] child 2786897 exited with
> code 0 after 2013.922094 seconds from start.

- Possibility 1) The process was terminated after 2013 seconds because it reached the end of the maximum runtime or was in idle mode for too long and is therefore no longer needed.
- Possibility 2) The process was terminated (hard) after 2013 seconds because it did not reach the end of the execution time.

Which is correct? Does anyone perhaps have a source for this as well?

Thank you!

Comment: Well two hints, the first is `NOTICE` (as opposed to `ERROR` or similar) and the second is exit code 0. These both indicate normal operation, and not an error condition, which is what your possibility 2 would fall under.

Comment: You can confirm or refute both of these suggestions by viewing the php.ini and/or other system setting files to establish max allowed execution time/memory/etc.

Comment: Having us guess at which of your own guesses for a log notice is, is not going to be a very academic or thorough resolution. As I say above, review the data rather than opinions.

Comment: Well, I thought there is some official documentation on those error codes?  I run a fully managed server and the admin says that my script throws a lot of these errors. But I don't assume them to be errors.